# How do I let proxylocal connect to my OpenVpn server?

Tags: openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server on a mac. I cannot port forward because of reasons. So i use the service called proxylocal that makes servers public and gives you a subdomain. I have the VPN server running on `localhost:1194`. However everytime I try, I get the output:

```
Connection has been terminated
```

ProxyLocal worked fine in other cases except of this. I have ip forwarding enabled and firewall does not block it.

Answer (score 1):

On their page, they say that the service is down with a listed alternative. Use that instead